# Search for pull requests that are created 1 month ago and earlier

Tags: github, github-search

I am looking for a query, that will fulfil that:

`is:pr is:open created:>=now-1m`
or
`is:pr is:open created:>={{manually entered DATE}}-1m`

Can `now` and `-1m` be dynamic? (So there won't be needed manual input)

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was not that bad. The following should work for you.

```
is:pr is:open created:<YYYY-MM-DD
```

[GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-when-an-issue-or-pull-request-was-closed).

Comment: Hey! Sorry, probably I was not specific enough. I wanted to know if it can be dynamic :)

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand but I guess this is not possible. I didn't found anything in the documentation nor in the GitHub community. If you like you can propose this feature [here](https://github.com/community/community/discussions). I would like to use it on GitHub.